# Perform GroupJoin and Join in single query in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to do a join inside a groupjoin using Linq. Here's the scenario - for each lineitem in an order, I want to get some attributes from the variant for that line item(such as variant options and imageid which are stored in variant and product databases). i want to join lineitem, variant and product databases to get these extra information for the lineitem and then groupjoin this lineitem with the order table. i have done this and got the desired result using two queries but I am not sure how many database queries are run. And in the first case(ie in the join, a limit cannot be specified so I just want to make sure that the first iqueryable in the code below is evaluated only when .ToListAsync() is called). Is this the right way to do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
  public async Task<dynamic> GetOrdersAsync(User user, int pageNumber = 1)
        {
            var perPage = 10;
            var lineItemAndVariant = from l in _context.LineItems
                                     join v in _context.Variants
                                     on l.EcomPlatformVariantId equals v.EcomPlatformVariantId
                                     join p in _context.Products
                                     on v.ProductId equals p.Id
                                     where p.UserId == user.Id
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         l.Id,
                                         l.OrderId,
                                         l.Price,
                                         l.Quantity,
                                         l.EcomPlatformLineItemId,
                                         l.EcomPlatformVariantId,
                                         l.Title,
                                         ImageId = v.ImageId ?? p.ThumbnailId, // for adding image 
                                         p.MyVendor,
                                         p.MyVendorId,
                                         v.Option1,
                                         v.Option2,
                                         v.Option3,
                                         p.VariantOption1Label,
                                         p.VariantOption2Label,
                                         p.VariantOption3Label
                                     };


            var orders = await _context.Orders
                .Where(o => o.UserId == user.Id)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.Id)
                .Skip(perPage * (pageNumber - 1)).Take(perPage)
                .GroupJoin(lineItemAndVariant, o => o.Id, l => l.OrderId,
                (o, lineItems) => new
                {
                    o.Id,
                    o.EcomPlatformOrderId,
                    o.CustomerEmail,
                    o.FirstName,
                    o.LastName,
                    o.Address1,
                    o.Address2,
                    o.City,
                    o.Company,
                    o.Country,
                    o.Currency,
                    o.OrderNumber,
                    o.Phone,
                    o.Province,
                    o.TotalPrice,
                    o.UserId,
                    o.Zip,
                    o.CreatedAt,
                    LineItems = lineItems
                })
                .AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();


            return orders;

        }
```

Comment: Yes, first query will run only when `.ToListAsync()`. If you used `Sql Server`, you could try `SQL Server Proiler` to record the generated query to check the query process.

Comment: @TaoZhou thanks, how many queries will be run in total, will the first query be combined with 2nd and they will be run together or will they be run as separate queries? And will the first query load everything from database since limit is not specified? (I dont specify limit since its an iqueryable so i thought i could just use it for joining with another query)

Comment: Will run together. will load everything.

Comment: @TaoZhou i see thats bad. how can I just perform it without loading everything in the first query? I know I can do a query first for just the orders and then run that first query that have orderIds from the order id list but it will need two queries(but i assume my code above is using two queries anyway right?)

Comment: Not sure the current query model for EF Core, you may try `SQL Server Proiler` to check the real query.